# Android Java regexp pattern

Tags: java, android, regex

I ping a host. In result a standard output. Below a REGEXP but it do not work correct. Where I did a mistake?

```
String REGEXP ="time=(\\\\d+)ms";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEXP);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            result = matcher.group(1);
        }
```

Comment: `\\d+` should be enough

Comment: problem solved. delete this post -_-

Comment: @Jonjongot - I think the OP needs to know *why?* :)

Comment: @TheLostMind Then somebody please add answer :p Btw Its been a while, and you are _growing_ so fast. almost 14k!

Comment: If you try to compare a `String` with this Regexp, you could simply use `result.matches(REGEXP)` in an `if-statement`. No need for `Pattern` or `Matcher` that way (note: if result is not a `String`, I don't know what the outcome will be).

Comment: @Jonjongot - So are you my friend :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `\\d+` in your regex because

Matcher looks for the pattern (using which it is created) and then tries to find every occurance of the pattern in the string being matched.

1. Use `while(matcher.group(1)` in case of multiple occurances.
2. each `()` represents a captured group.

Answer (score 1):

You have too many backslashes. Assuming you want to get the number from a string like "time=32ms", then you need:

```
String REGEXP ="time=(\\d+)ms";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEXP);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(result);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        result = matcher.group(1);
    }
```

Explanation: The search pattern you are looking for is "\d", meaning a decimal number, the "+" means 1 or more occurrences.

To get the "\" to the matcher, it needs to be escaped, and the escape character is also "\".

The brackets define the matching group that you want to pick out.

With "\\\\d+", the matcher sees this as "\\d+", which would match a backslash followed by one or more "d"s. The first backslash protects the second backslash, and the third protects the fourth.